# Nex js: Should next js server deal with user specific data?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am currently learning about next js and I have a few questions in mind.
These are not real projects I am working on but just examples.

Let's say I have my frontend app running on 'example.com' and an api server 'api.example.com'. The api is using normal session-cookie authentication for the spa.

I have a page called `pages/projects` which shows the user's current project, now for ssr should the server just pre-render a loading state of the page and let the client fetch the data from the api? Or should I use the user cookies and query the api during ssr in order to load the completed version of the page?

```
const Page: NextPage<Props> = ({ projects }: Props) => {
  return(
    <>
      {projects.map((project) => {
        // render out ProjectItem component.
      })}
    </>
  )
}

Page.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  if (context.req) {
    // fetch data using the user's cookies
  } else {
    // fetch data on client side 
  }
  // the part above could be abstracted to be reused.
  return {
    projects: result.data
  }
}

export default Page
```

Or stick to `useEffect` and just pre render a loading page?
This only concerns the first page load, as navigating to it through `next/link` will make the client directly contact the api so is that the right thing to do also in the first load?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends. What is your end goal here? SEO? Code maintenance? Fast TTI?

Comment: @PsyGik well I guess seo doesn't matter here much. The main goal is user experience and speed.

Comment: Yea. That's my question too now. I'm building app using Next. Part of the app is publicly visible (and Server pre-render make sense) but the app is just for logged users. The content is user-specific, but I don't want use different path for each user. So is there any better way than give up on pre-rendering and serving page with async API call with Next?
Thanks